# How do I convert this FOR loop into a WHILE loop so that it also counts for Consonants? (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, count

How do I convert this FOR loop into a WHILE loop so that it also counts for Consonants? I know how to do a basic counter using While loop so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelsCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a string: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Number of Vowels in the string: " + vowCount(str) + "\n");
    }

    public static int vowCount(String str) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++) {
            if (str.charAt(index) == 'a' || str.charAt(index) == 'e' ||
                str.charAt(index) == 'i' || str.charAt(index) == 'o' ||
                str.charAt(index) == 'u') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function `count` that counts both consonants and vowels, using a `while` loop (although the kind of loop doesn't matter really):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelsCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input a string: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        Counts counts = count(str);

        System.out.println("Number of Vowels in the string: " + counts.getVowels());
        System.out.println("Number of Consonants in the string: " + counts.getConsonants());
    }

    public static Counts count(String str) {
        int vowCount = 0;
        int consCount = 0;

        str = str.toLowerCase();

        int i = str.length();
        while(i-- > 0) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                switch(ch) {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'u':
                        vowCount++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        consCount++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return new Counts(vowCount, consCount);
    }

    public static final class Counts {
        private int vowels;
        private int consonants;

        public Counts(int vowels, int consonants) {
            this.vowels = vowels;
            this.consonants = consonants;
        }

        public int getVowels() {
            return vowels;
        }

        public int getConsonants() {
            return consonants;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, how the function works is that it loops over all the characters in the string (in reverse), and then first checks if it is a letter (between `a` and `z`), and if it is, then it must be either a vowel or a consonant. So we just need to check which one and increment the respective counter.

Comment: This is bad practice to use array for that reason. You have to define custom class.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik You mean the array that I return in the function? Yeah, fair enough. I suppose it should just return a map (or a custom class like you say).

Comment: I wish I knew what's good and what's bad. I guess it takes years of practice.

Comment: @Elias: Yep, practice makes perfect, but it also helps to read Java related resources (like _Effective Java_). Or for example reading the feedback people get on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java). In the end though, nobody writes perfect code, so don't get too obsessed about it. (btw, slightly ironic how his edited code now returns an `int[]` :) ).

Comment: @TiiJ7 thanks for an advice, I appreciated it! Your code works great btw and does exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 2):

A `while()` loop has at its argument a `termination statement`, that means instead of initialising, and incrementing your index you have to set your termination as while parameter. **EDIT** the `index`variable has to be initialised before your loop.

**In your case:**

```
while(index != str.length()){
     //rest of the statement, those from your for loop
     index++;
}
```

Comment: Your describtion is right but the code will not compile. The variable `index` has to be defined prior to the `while`-statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is ready `LetterCount` class, that could incapsulate all glogic for letter count:

```
public final class LetterCount {

    private final String str;
    private final int vowel;
    private final int consonant;

    public static LetterCount create(String str) {
        int[] count = count(str);
        return new LetterCount(str, count[0], count[1]);
    }

    private static int[] count(String str) {
        int i = str.length();
        int[] count = new int[2];

        while (--i >= 0) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));

            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                count[0]++;
            else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                count[1]++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    private LetterCount(String str, int vowel, int consonant) {
        this.str = str;
        this.vowel = vowel;
        this.consonant = consonant;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public int getVowel() {
        return vowel;
    }

    public int getConsonant() {
        return consonant;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Stream-version can be written even shorter: `str.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u').count();`

Comment: Your While loop looks legit! Would you be able to edit it so that it counts for Consonants as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can count consonants by initializing another variable, add it by 1 in else condition when your if criteria is not met.
for while loop you can do something like this.

```
int countVow = 0;
int index = 0;
while(index != str.length())
{
    if(vowel)
    {
        countVow++;
    }

    index++
}
int countCon = index = countVow;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, where is the use of array in above answer ?

Comment: @Alan, you can accept this answer now :) 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine:-

```
public static int vowCount(String str) {
            int count = 0;
            int index = 0;
            while (index < str.length()) {
                if (str.charAt(index) == 'a' || str.charAt(index) == 'e' || str.charAt(index) == 'i' || str.charAt(index) == 'o' || str.charAt(index) == 'u') {
                    count++;
                }
                index++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `for` by a `while` is not required to also count the consonants.
Both can do that and a `for` that is better designed to iterate until a specific index seems better for your use case.

The idea would be to define a String of vowels and a String of consonants and for each encountered character you increment the counter according to the matching of these `String`s.

```
static final String vowels = "aei...";
static final String consonants = "bcdf...";

public static int[] vowCount(String str){
  int countV = 0;
  int countC = 0;
  for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++){
    String currentChar = str.substring(index, index+1);
    if (vowels.contains(currentChar)){
     countV++;
    }
    else if (consonants.contains(currentChar)){
     countC++;
    }
  }

  return new int[]{countV, countC};
}
```

I returned an array of `int[]` but you could also return an instance of a `Count` class you can define to hold the two data.

Comment: This is bad practice to use array for that reason. You have to define custom class.

Comment: I don't like that either. That's why I specified "I returned an array of int[] but you could also return an instance of a Count class you can define to hold the two data."